# Technical name for "many-to-many" mappings

Tags: functions

A one-to-one mapping is a bijection. A many-to-one mapping is a "general function" and might also be a "surjective function".

Is there a similarly technical name for a many-to-many mapping, or should I just write "many-to-many" whenever describing such a thing. Same question for a "one-to-many" mapping (perhaps "inverse general function")?

EDIT: For what I mean by a "many-to-many" mapping:

```
Set 1: A, B, C, D
Set 2: W, X, Y, Z

A maps to W
B maps to W and X
C and D map to Y and Z (many-to-many relationship)
```

Comment: What does many-to-many even mean?

Comment: In this case, multivalued is probably the right term, as janmarqz suggests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another common name is **[relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation)**.

Comment: Thanks! Can you double check your link? I think you had a little copy-paste mishap.

Comment: @Kevin thanks! Yes, I was trying to cut and paste on a tablet and I'm not very good at it.

Answer (score 3):

**Multivalued function** is used. In places like **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)** you can see more details and many other technical situations.